# "SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database" when accessing php file on localhost with MAMP

Tags: php, mysql

I am running OSX and trying to access a database using MAMP on localhost.
I get the following error: "SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database".
I have googled and tried everything. The files are from the textbook Murach's PHP and SQL. Its only this group of PHP files of all the lessons responding this way. These php files have hardly been edited except for the necessary $username and $password fields being updated which looks as follows:

```
 $dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=my_guitar_shop1';
 $username = 'root';
 $password = 'root';
```

Comment: check database with your given name is actually exist or not?

Comment: the error is becuase of given database not exists check the name and then proceed.

Comment: the database you mentioned does not exist. check if database exists and also note that you must use either mysqli or PDO as mysql is deprecated.

Comment: Try to run `mysql -u root -proot -e "USE DATABASE my_guitar_shop1"`. See if the database exists.

Comment: When I run that statement in terminal I get: -bash: mysql: command not found. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Check that the database `my_guitar_shop1` actually exist. Go to phpMyAdmin (Open Webstart page -> phpMyAdmin). In the left, you have the list of your databases. If you don't see `my_guitar_shop1`, then you have to create it.

Comment: I forgot to install the my_guitar_shop1 database. Thanks.